# python matplotlib cannot show the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code is :

```
  1 import matplotlib
  2 matplotlib.use('Agg')
  3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  4 def main():
  5    
  6     
  7     dataX = [1,2,3,4]
  8     dataY = [1,2,3,1]
  9     plt.plot(dataX,dataY)
 10     plt.title("pic")
 11     plt.xlabel("x")
 12     plt.ylabel("y")
 13     plt.show()
 14 if __name__ == "__main__":
 15     main()
```

The code can run successfully, but no graph pops up. Earlier, I didn't use `matplotlib.use('Agg')` and just `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` then, I got the error `ImportError: Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.` I tried many ways on StackOverflow, but all doesn't work. The error info shows: [image]

Comment: The `'Agg'` backend cannot show any figure (you can still save it though). In order to show the figure you need to use any of the [interactive backends](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#the-builtin-backends). The error you get can be taken literally. If you want to use the GTK3Agg backend, you need to install pygtk.

Comment: Yes, I've tried ```Qt5Agg``` ,```Qt4Agg``` and something like these, and then I got error ```ValueError: Unrecognized backend string``` I have run ```pip install pygtk```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a figure in the console:

```
import tkinter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():  
    dataX = [1,2,3,4]
    dataY = [1,2,3,1]
    plt.plot(dataX,dataY)
    plt.title("pic")
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")
    plt.show()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can also try to save a figure:

```
def main():  
    dataX = [1,2,3,4]
    dataY = [1,2,3,1]
    plt.plot(dataX,dataY)
    plt.title("pic")
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")
    plt.savefig("figure.png")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: There is still no graph pops up, but save figure is worked.

Comment: Tkinter must be installed and should not be the first two lines ("import matplotlib"
  and "matplotlib.use('Agg')")  What is the error information?

Comment: There is no error when I use python3, but it doesn't have a graph showing up. My python version is 2.7.5.

Comment: I use python 3.7.3 and this code is workking correctly.

Comment: As mentioned by Ernest, `pygtk` needs to be installed. Also note that `plt.savefig` needs to be called before `plt.show` because `plt.show` typically erases the plot.

Comment: Yes, plt.savefig needs to be called before plt.show, but in this case it works both ways. I will edit the answer now.